# VBA: Setting Colors to Excel Column, colors imported from text file

Tags: vba, excel

Excel VBA: I have a task to modify the background color of few columns, based on inputs given in a text file. I was able to do this using hex color. Now I have the requirement to support colors in simple English. 
The text file will now have data like

```
columnname1,red
columnname2,green
```

So I have to map this "red" to the colorConstant number 3 to make it work. If I need to allow all supported colors 
[Check here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/get-list-color-constants-t2746407.html), do I need to write IF ELSE for all of them. Is there a simple way for that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe that makes no difference. It can reduce some lines compared to if statement. Is there a way I can set it like .color=rgb & "Red". I see rgbRed is a color constant.

Comment: I would create a lookup table of color vs. index and use that. There's no easy way to create a string version of a constant name and convert that to the constant's value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **Collection** to store the mapping :

```
Public indexOf As Collection

Sub map(color As String, index As Integer)
    Call indexOf.Add(index, color)
End Sub

Sub init()
    Set indexOf = New Collection

    map "red", 3
    map "green", 4
    map "blue", 5
End Sub

Sub test()
    init

    [A1].Interior.ColorIndex = indexOf("red")
    [A2].Interior.ColorIndex = indexOf("green")
    [A3].Interior.ColorIndex = indexOf("blue")
End Sub
```